# InvalidCastException C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm stuck on this issue. Please help.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmd.CommandText = "hhrcv_upsert_grv_sku";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_delivery_bay_code", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = this.bayCode.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_company_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = lblCompany_id_no.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_order_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = this.orderCode.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_sku_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = lblSku_id_no.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_price", OracleDbType.Number).Value = txtPrice.Text.ToString();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pv_error", OracleDbType.VarChar));
cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

string pv_error;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
pv_error = (string)cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value;

if (cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value.ToString().Equals("Invalid"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("valid");
}
```

Getting **InvalidCastException was unhandled** on the line that reads `pv_error = (string)cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value;`

Not sure how to fix.

thanks.

Comment: Is it a `string`? Later in the code you call `ToString()` on it. This would be redundant if it wasn't a `string`.

Comment: try to use cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value.ToString().

Comment: that's because you are setting up parameters of type Oracle.Number with strings.

Comment: Debugger will tell you the problem, exactly. See the type in `cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the type of Parameters["pv_error"].Value is probably not a string.

```
pv_error = (string)cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value;
```

try to replace it with:

```
pv_error = cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value.ToString();
```

As you do in the next line. And you have to test if Value != null.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["pv_error"].Value)
```

Convert.ToString() handles null.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        cmd.CommandText = "hhrcv_upsert_grv_sku";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("pv_delivery_bay_code", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = this.bayCode.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_company_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = lblCompany_id_no.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_order_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = this.orderCode.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_sku_id_no", OracleDbType.Number).Value = lblSku_id_no.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pn_price", OracleDbType.Number).Value = txtPrice.Text.ToString();

    var pv_error = cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pv_error", OracleDbType.VarChar));
    pv_error.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    if (pv_error.Value.ToString().Equals("Invalid"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("valid");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be useful to see the actual value of `pv_error` that is causing the exception, but since `pv_error` is an **output parameter** - if there is no 'error', it will come out as `NULL` and therefore cause an **InvalidCastException**

I think some checking prior to setting would solve the problem.